# MKMapView reset back to world view

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

How do I reset an `MKMapView` back to the world view zoom level?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(mapView.centerCoordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(180, 360));
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

This will set a new region for the map view using the current center coordinate, and the maximum possible span (180 degrees of latitude, 360 degrees of longitude).

Answer (score 38):

The map rect for the world is stored as a constant named `MKMapRectWorld`.

```
MKCoordinateRegion worldRegion = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(MKMapRectWorld);
map.region = worldRegion;
```

One other way is to set the zoom level of the map. Although the MapKit framework does not support zoom levels as Google Maps API does, you can use this [category extension](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/set-the-zoom-level-of-an-mkmapview/) written by Troy Brant.

Set the center coordinate to 0, 0 with zoom level 0 to get the same result.

```
[map setCenterCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, 0) zoomLevel:0 animated:0];
```

Answer (score 4):

For those hoping to do this in Swift:

```
let region = MKCoordinateRegion(.world)
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

`MKMapView` can not zoom out to show the whole world. No matter what you are using, `MKMapRectWorld`, zoom level 0, or `MKCoordinateSpanMake(180, 360)`.